# How do I execute curl stdout with interactive prompt?

Tags: shell, sh, iterm2

I have a shell script `setup.sh`, written somewhat like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

bash <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liuchengxu/space-vim/master/install.sh)
```

I already set the mode to executable. But when I do `./setup.sh` to execute this script in terminal, I got the error saying.

```
line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What's wrong with my script?

I'm using iTerm and zsh.

Thank you!

Comment: You're running your command through `#!/bin/sh` - this is not `bash`. `/bin/sh` does not understand the `<(` process substitution.

Comment: @Corion Thank you!. changed it to `#!/bin/bash` solved it. lol

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Corion I wasn't suppose to use `#!/bin/sh` with `<(` , change it to `#!/bin/bash` worked for me.